# Prove inequality for complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Can anyone help me or at least give me some hints 
 
how to prove following inequality  :

$
\lvert z-a\rvert \le \lvert \lvert a\rvert-\lvert z\rvert\rvert + \lvert z\rvert*\lvert arg (z/a)\rvert
$

for any $ z, a \in \Bbb C, a \neq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this image helps as a hint.
[image]

The messy algebraic part seems proving that
$$\left|z-|a|\cdot e^{i\arg z}\right|\le|z|\cdot\left|\arg\left(\frac za\right)\right|$$
(That is, the arc is longer than the chord).

Comment: is that always true that 
$ \lvert z \rvert arg (z/a)  $ is a lenght of arc from z to intersection of line through a and (0,0) with circle through z and center (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
By dividing $|a|$ from both sides you can assume $a=1$. What is the geometric meaning of that?